# Mongo / Express Query Nested _id from query string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using: node/express/mongodb/mongoose

With the setup listed above, I have created my schema and model and can query as needed. What I'm wondering how to do though is, pass the express request.query object to Model.find() in mongoose to match and query the _id of a nested document. In this instance, the query may look something like:

```
http://domain.com/api/object._id=57902aeec07ffa2290f179fe
```

Where object is a nested object that exists elsewhere in the database. I can easily query other fields. _id is the only one giving an issue. It returns an empty array of matches.

Can this be done?

This is an example and not the ACTUAL schema but this gets the point across..

```
let Category = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})

let Product = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description:String,
    category:Category
})

// sample category..
{
    _id:ObjectId("1234567890"),
    name: 'Sample Category'
}

// sample product
{
    _id:ObjectId("0987654321"),
    name:'Sample Product',
    description:'Sample Product Description',
    category: {
        _id:ObjectId("1234567890"),
        name: 'Sample Category'
    }
}
```

So, what I'm looking for is... if I have the following in express..

```
app.get('/products',function(req,res,next){
    let query = req.query
    ProductModel.find(query).exec(function(err,docs){
        res.json(docs)
    })
})
```

This would allow me to specify anything I want in the query parameters as a query. So I could..

```
http://domain.com/api/products?name=String
http://domain.com/api/products?description=String
http://domain.com/api/products?category.name=String
```

I can query by category.name like this, but I can't do:

```
http://domain.com/api/products?category._id=1234567890
```

This returns an empty array

Comment: Please add some code or schema

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to `http://domain.com/api/object/57902aeec07ffa2290f179fe` and try

```
app.get('/api/object/:_id', function(req, res) {

    // req._id is Mongo Document Id
    // change MyModel to your model name 
    MyModel.findOne( {'_id' : req._id }, function(err, doc){
        // do smth with this document 
        console.log(doc);
    });

});
```

---

or try this one
`http://domain.com/api/object?id=57902aeec07ffa2290f179fe`

```
app.get('/api/object', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.param('id');
    MyModel.findOne( {'_id' : id }, function(err, doc){
        console.log(doc);
    });
})
```

---

1. First of all increase your skills in [getting URL and POST Parameters](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters) by this article.
2. Read official [Express 4.x API Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Comment: See the updated post and see if that makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I feel ridiculous. It works just as I posted above.. after I fixed an error in my schema.